# When to Use Sorting Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm a mostly self-taught programmer, I'm in my freshman year of college going towards a BS in CompSci. Last year I would do some of the homework for the AP CompSci kids, and when they got to sorting algorithms, I understood what they did, but my question was what is a case where one is used? I know this may seem like a horrible, or ridiculous question, but other than a few cases I can think of, I don't understand when one would use a sorting algorithm. I understand that they are essential to know, and that they are foundational algorithms. But in the day to day, when are they used?

Comment: for example if you want to search something, there is the dichotomy algorithme, right? but this one, you have to use it on a sorted list, right? ^_^

Comment: ...when you need things sorted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it is too-broad and/or primary opinion based.

Comment: You will rarely write sorting algorithm code as there are library functions that do that.

Comment: Um... You use sorting algorithms when you need things sorted. Most times, there are library functions that do so that you can use, but there are cases when those library functions don't work for your specific data.

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't need to implement them yourself, and can rely on those provided to you. eg. http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-list

Comment: @RSSM: Provided, of course, that your code has anything to do with .net. For those that don't use .net languages, there are other alternatives, as well as need to write your own. I've written my own quicksort and combsort in the last year because canned versions didn't work with my data.

Comment: When you need one, you'll know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting algorithm is an algorithm that arrange the list of elements in certain order. You can use such algorithms when you want the elements in some order.

For example:

1. Sorting strings on basis of lexicographical order. This makes several computation easier (like searching, insertion, deletion provided appropiate data structure is used)
2. Sorting integers as part of preprocessing of some algorithms. Suppose you have lot of queries in data base to find an integer, you will want to apply binary search. For it to be applicable, input must be sorted.
3. In many computational geometry algorithms (like convex hull), sorting the co-ordinates is the first step you do.

So, basically, if you want some ordering, you resort to sorting algorithms!